# How do I store my trained model on Google Colab and retrieve weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, google-colaboratory

i entered my code in google colab and uploaded my dataset it starts training the model but when i open it again after few hours it already stopped and i don't get any weights...can some tell me whats the issue here

how can i create check point in my code?  Can you please mention code for that. It would be great.

[link to google colaboratory file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lsg8HkguD8BWsFgvVS7lAQD3rfa_DZnq)

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions here. For checkpoints, it is possible to write to Google Drive, but as for the code, it depends on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: One issue could be that your training is taking too long - Google Colab resets every 12hours, and your notebook must be ran again, from the top, if this happens. Make sure you've changed your `Runtime type` to `GPU` (and that your model is configured to use it) to speed up your process.

Comment: its already set to gpu but process take more than just 12 hours it need around 5-6 day to run it completely @JulioCezarSilva

Comment: one friend told me that check point can solve this issue when i restart the process after 12 hours it start where it stopped and the thing is i don't know how write check points and where to add those checkpoint in code @AndrewFan

Comment: Tensorflow has a guide for making checkpoints [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints). Informing us exactly what type of model yours is - with a minimal code example, if possible - could help us come with a more specific solution.

Comment: @JulioCezarSilva i just added the link of the code can you check it and help me out?

Answer (score -1):

In googlr colab you have to stay connected with internet
when you train download the weights because when connection lost your all thigs will be lost only code will be saved there if you have saved